# How do I sort my comments/replies/replies to replies data properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am using Nodejs, Express, MySQL, EJS.

Users are able to create posts and comment/reply to comments/reply to replies on those posts.

The problem: I don't know how to sort the data into objects/arrays in a way that will allow me to render them in EJS. I know how to do it for comments and replies to the comments, but not to replies to replies. How to create an object/array(or objects/arrays) which will make it "easier/simpler" to manage the comments, replies and replies of replies of replies(...etc)?

The idea: I believe the end product should look something like this:

- When rendering EJS, it will check the sorted data for comments, if there are comments, it will create 1 container div for that single comment(and for the replies of that single comment), each other comment will have it's own container div.
- In that container div, will be the main comment div which will contain only the comment.
- Below the comment div will be the replies to the comment div(maybe the replies to replies will be stored here too, or a div specifically for that will be created)

  - (I don't need to do it in this way, you are allowed to do it in your own way, I just think this is not a bad way to do it)

The "comments" MySQL table is:

```
ID     comment                         ReplyToCommentID
--------------------------------------------------------
1 | First Updated Comment              | NULL
2 | Second Comment                     | NULL
3 | Third Comment                      | NULL
4 | 4th Comment                        | NULL
5 | This is a reply to comment ID 1    |  1
6 | Reply to Comment ID 4              |  4
7 | Testing  here                      | NULL
8 | TriHard 7 comment id 7             | NULL
```

The value in ReplyToCommentID means that comment is a reply to the comment with the ID of that value, the comments with ID 5 and 6 are replies to the comments with ID 1 and 4, if it's NULL, it means it's a normal comment to the post.

Getting them from MySQL to Node returns them in this format:

```
[{"id":1,"comment":"First Updated Comment","ReplyToCommentID":null},{"id":2,"comment":"Second Comment","ReplyToCommentID":null},{"id":3,"comment":"Third Comment","ReplyToCommentID":null},{"id":4,"comment":"4th Comment","ReplyToCommentID":null},{"id":5,"comment":"This is a reply to comment ID 1","ReplyToCommentID":1},{"id":6,"comment":"Reply to Comment ID 4","ReplyToCommentID":4},{"id":7,"comment":"Testing here","ReplyToCommentID":null},{"id":8,"comment":"TriHard 7 comment id 7","ReplyToCommentID":null}]
```

Separating the comments and replies into their own object gives this. (Obviously)

```
this is replies {"1":"This is a reply to comment ID 1","4":"Reply to Comment ID 4"}
This is comments {"1":"First Updated Comment","2":"Second Comment","3":"Third Comment","4":"4th Comment","7":"Testing here","8":"TriHard 7 comment id 7"}
```

I have spent a couple of days trying to figure this out, but it seems it's too much for my "student experience". (I am self-taught so I don't have someone to ask for help in real life)

I would be very thankful if you help me with this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have got a list. But you actually want to have a "tree view". So it would make sense to turn your list into a tree. At that point we can also sort out the root nodes:

```
 const roots = [];
 const byId = new Map();

 for(const reply of replies)
   byId.set(reply.id, reply);

 for(const reply of replies) {
   const {ReplyToComment} = reply;
   if(ReplyToComment) {
    const parent = byId.get(ReplyToComment);
    (parent.children || (parent.children = [])).push(reply);
   } else {
    roots.push(reply);
   }
}
```

Now `roots` looks like this:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  /*...*/
  children: [{
    id:2,
    ReplyToComment:1
  }, /*...*/]
}, /*...*/ ]
```

How to then render it to your page is your thing, however a recursive approach would look like:

```
 function show(replies, depth = 0) {
   for(const reply of replies) {
     console.log(" ".repeat(depth) + reply.comment);
     show(reply.children || [], depth + 1);
    }
 }

 show(roots);
```

Now the console output will be

```
 comment
  reply
   reply
  reply
  ...
```

Something similar can be adopted with html.